# Switching between OSs from icon

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have Windows 7 and 8 installed on two partitions on an SSD, with 7 as the default. I sometimes have to switch to windows 8 to do some work. What I would like is to create a commandline script or something, which when run, will restart the computer and boot into the second OS. Is something like this possible? I know I can just use the boot menu, but I can't help thinking there should be a cooler way to do this.

Comment: Not easily but you could write a script that changes the default OS through `bcdedit`.

Comment: I'll write an answer when I get to my PC but have a read of: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/213776-bcdedit-changing-defaults.html - there is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without being in front of a Win7 or Win8 machine at the moment, I assume you could build a batch script similar to this... (Replace `<id>` with the identifier of the OS you want to boot)

```
bcdedit /default <id>
shutdown -r -t 02
```

To find the ID of the OS you use the `bcdedit /enum` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program called [iReboot](http://neosmart.net/iReboot/). It is a lightweight program (400kb memory usage according to the website) which runs in the background on the taskbar. You click the icon, and choose the OS you want to boot in.

[image]

Note: iReboot is a WINDOWS ONLY program, so you can use it to boot into Linux OSes but you can not boot to windows from Linux. Also, I'm just a happy user of the program, no connection with it.

---

If you really want a command line option, [iReboot 2 has command line scripting support](https://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=6431).

Syntax:

`iReboot.exe [/sticky yes|no] [/reboot yes|no] /target {guid}`

> /sticky: Whether to make this entry the default indefinitely or only
> for the next boot
>
> /reboot: Reboot after changing the selection, or
> just apply the changes upon next boot
>
> /target: The BCD {ID} for the
> entry you wish to boot into